# How to put a literal and variable inside a tag?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to create the xsl for the following tag:

```
<role roletype="Learner">
```

Learner is held in a variable labeled $wsRole.

This code is not working:

```
 <xsl:variable name="fullWsRole">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $wsRole,'&quot;')"/>
 </xsl:variable>            

 <role roletype="{$fullWsRole}">
 </role>
```

How do I create the node

```
<role roletype="Learner">    ?
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="fullWsRole" select="'Learner'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <role roletype="{$fullWsRole}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<role roletype="Learner"/>
```

**Explanation**: Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Template)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming variable `$wsRole` contains `Learner`

```
<xsl:variable name="wsRole">Learner</xsl:variable>
```

and expected result is

```
<role roletype="Learner"></role>
```

simply use:

```
<role roletype="{$wsRole}"></role>
```

Comment: thank you. $wsRole does contain Learner.  I tried that and am getting the following error: Variable "$wsRole" used but not declared

Comment: @Kevin, Because you must declare `$wsRole`. See updated answer.